# How to change common sections of a page based on different routes

Tags: angular

Let say we have a main app component like below. There are two route outlets ( 1 is a primary and another one a named outlet called "common-section". This page is loaded once we hit "http://localhost:4200/" route
[image: app.component.html]

My task is to load different components into "common-section" router outlet based on the different routes. Eg : If I am on "http://localhost:4200/" route then "common-section" should load some component say "latest news" and if I am on "http://localhost:4200/news" then "related articles" component must be loaded under "common-section" router outlet and so on.

I have tried adding named router outer in the app.component.html itself and tried loading different component in "http://localhost:4200/news" section using "outlet" property in the route but it didnt work

[image: router snipped]

Comment: `path` property in the router should match current path in the URL, for the `PreviousComponent` it should be `/news` rather than 'related articles'